# Why there is the difference in Oracle PL/SQL response time within SQL Developer vs. SQL Plus?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have PL/SQL function that returns cursor that holds 28 columns and 8100 rows.  When I execute that function from SQL Plus I got the results right away and in SQL Developer I'm running script that takes looong time (about 80 seconds). The same happen from Java code.  When number of columns reduced to 2 then I got response in less than 4 seconds.  Can someone explain what is going on in this case?

Comment: Well SQL Developer is written in Java too, whereas SQL*Plus is native code. So there's a clue.  What does your table look like?

Comment: Is this a remote database? If SQL*Plus is running on the same server as the database, and SQL Developer is accessing it over a network, then that could be a factor, particularly if you have LOB data, or the size of the returned columns is unknown (so it has to allocate more memory and bandwidth than it really needs). Presumably you could check that by running the Java version locally. Also from Java you could specify the column sizes and see if that helps.

Comment: Rather obvious no, SQL Developer has many more layers in addition to the streamlined tool that is made to interface smartly with the database, called : SQLPLUS. Something that can slow performance down, is just displaying data on your screen. If you let massive amounts of data being scrolled on your window, it can slow down seriously. In that case, just put another non related window (windows explorer, browser, ..) fullscreen, until the query is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest experiment to make is changing the "SQL Array Fetch Size" in SQL Developer, which defaults to 50. If you see results from bumping it to 500, there's the answer.

Interestingly, the default for the equivalent SQL*Plus parameter is only 15, but as APC said, SQL*Plus has the advantage of being native.

If changing "SQL Array Fetch Size" does not do anything, the next thing to look at is JDBC settings, which SQL Developer uses and SQL*Plus does not.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers before mine...

SQL*PLus sends the data straight back to the screen as soon as the first rows are returned whereas SQL Developer has to find the size of the resultset to return in advance of displaying records.

This might explain why there is a delay for SQL Developer especially if the resultset is large or takes a long time to fully return (e.g. if the execution path is complicated).